# how to debug client-side javascript served in static files by node.js in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to debug client-side javascript  served by node.js as a static resource within VSCode. Is this possible ?

I am able to debug server-side  javascript following this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

I am able to debug the javascript that is served by express.static() within the browser itself by using the developer tools.

However i don't understand how to debug that code within VSCode itself.

I have tried this : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging but i cannot set any breakpoints in the client-side javascript code.